# Issue with deployment of a smart contract using ehereum wallet in private network

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I am trying to deploy smart contract in the private network using Ethereum Wallet client (mist) . Although i have enough funds the application complains me that i have insufficient funds for * gas price+value.

smart contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract HelloWorld {
  uint256 counter = 0;

  /* Constructor */
  function Increase() public {
    counter++;
  }

  function Decrease() public {
    counter--;
  }

  function GetCounter() public constant returns(uint256){
    return counter;
  }
}
```

** genesis.json **

```
{ 
  "config": { 
    "chainId": 0, 
    "homesteadBlock": 0, 
    "eip155Block": 0, 
    "eip158Block": 0 
  }, 
  "alloc" : {}, 
  "coinbase" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
  "difficulty" : "0x20000", 
  "extraData" : "", 
  "gasLimit" : "0x2fefd8", 
  "nonce" : "0x0000000000000041", 
  "mixhash" : "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000‌​0000000", 
  "parentHash" : "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000‌​0000000", 
  "timestamp" : "0x00"
}
```

Geth command:

> geth --datadir=./chaindata

Note: I am new to the ethereum block chain development so trying to get hands on experience by creating a private net

Comment: Can you provide your `geth` and `mist` start scripts? My suspicion is your instance of Mist is connecting to a different network and not to your private blockchain. Also, please include your genesis config.

Comment: {
  "config": {
        "chainId": 0,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
  "alloc"      : {},
  "coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "difficulty" : "0x20000",
  "extraData"  : "",
  "gasLimit"   : "0x2fefd8",
  "nonce"      : "0x0000000000000041",
  "mixhash"    : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp"  : "0x00"
}

Comment: step 1 for opening geth client and block chain: geth --datadir=./chaindata
step 2 for opening new client: geth attach  
step 3 for opening wallet: Ehereum wallet(MIST) GUI

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues...

You mention that your account has funds. How did you add ether to your accounts on the private blockchain? There is no indication of funds being initialized in the genesis.json config. You should have something like this:

```
{
  ...
  "alloc": {
        "ACCOUNT_ADDRESS": {
            "balance": "30000000000000000000000000000"
        }
    }
}
```

This will seed your account with 300 ether. You'll need to create an account on the private blockchain first and use that in the config file.

Second, you're setting the network id to 0 in genesis.json. Choose a different id.

Third, as mentioned in my comment, your not connecting to your private network. You need to add the `--networkid` option when starting geth, passing in the network id you set in genesis.json. When starting geth, you should see something like this in your output:

> INFO [01-11|14:21:03] Initialising Ethereum protocol
>   versions="[63 62]" network=1

With the network id being whatever you set in genesis.json. If you see `network=1`, you're connecting to the main network.

If you're just starting out with Solidity, you may want to consider not creating a private blockchain just yet. You can use Remix for a fully sandboxed development environment, or use the Ropsten test network.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I have mined some ether using miner.start(3); using another console with geth attach command. At this moment i opened the MIST and its automatically connected to the private network and displayed the amount of ether mined. After i tried to add contract with the above mentioned HelloWorld code